# Error for download many different packages on mac (beginner

Tags: r, macos, package

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
```

> There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
> binary source needs_compilation tidyverse  1.3.1  1.3.2             FALSE
>
> installing the source package ‘tidyverse’
>
> trying URL
> 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tidyverse_1.3.2.tar.gz' Content
> type 'application/x-gzip' length 702514 bytes (686 KB)
> ================================================== downloaded 686 KB
>
> - installing *source* package ‘tidyverse’ ...
>   ** package ‘tidyverse’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>   ** using staged installation
>   ** R
>   ** inst
>   ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
>   ** help
>   *** installing help indices
>   *** copying figures
>   ** building package indices
>   ** installing vignettes
>   ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
>   ** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
>   ** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
> - DONE (tidyverse)
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
> ‘/private/var/folders/44/sqf7d5rs28d45tczm_r1qyfm0000gn/T/Rtmpx35lqL/downloaded_packages’

```
install.packages("esquisse")
```

> There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
> binary source needs_compilation esquisse  1.1.0  1.1.2             FALSE
>
> installing the source package ‘esquisse’
>
> trying URL
> 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/esquisse_1.1.2.tar.gz' Content
> type 'application/x-gzip' length 2460073 bytes (2.3 MB)
> ================================================== downloaded 2.3 MB
>
> - installing *source* package ‘esquisse’ ...
>   ** package ‘esquisse’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>   ** using staged installation
>   ** R
>   ** inst
>   ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
>   ** help
>   *** installing help indices
>   *** copying figures
>   ** building package indices
>   ** installing vignettes
>   ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
>   ** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
>   ** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
> - DONE (esquisse)
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
> ‘/private/var/folders/44/sqf7d5rs28d45tczm_r1qyfm0000gn/T/Rtmpx35lqL/downloaded_packages’

I tried install.packages("esquisse"),  directly search it in "packages" and install from CRAN, and

```
# install and load required packages
required.packages <- c("tidyverse", "ggplot2", "esquisse", "psych", "DataExplorer", "data.table")
new.packages <- required.packages[!(required.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)
lapply(required.packages, require, character.only = TRUE)
```

same problem for above three methods I tried. Could you give me some advices?

Comment: What problem did you have? When I read `DONE (tidyverse)` after all the log text that looks like it installed successfully.

Comment: have you tried loading the package after you download it? It does not automatically load the package and you have to run the command `library(tidyverse)`.